# Return column index where column name partially matches string

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a cluster of sequential columns whose column headers vary but all contain a key word, "Fluency". For example, one column might be called English Fluency and another Spanish Fluency. Another might be Fluency in Another Language.  I want to return the position of the first such column and last such column.

I tried this, and it works perfectly when the column name matches the word "Fluency" exactly, but does not work for partial matches. I get the result I am looking for only when the column name is "Fluency" exactly, but not "English Fluency."

This is for an apps script project

```js
function findColumnNumbers() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');

    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var header_row_num = 1;
    var header = data[header_row_num - 1]

    //define the string you want to search for
    var searchString = 'Fluency'

    var colNum = header.indexOf(searchString) + 1;
    var colNumLast = header.lastIndexOf(searchString) + 1;
    console.log(colNum);
    console.log(colNumLast);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take the value of that column (`indexOf(searchString) + 1` this one for example) and check if it's the exact same as Fluency, if so then console.log it. The same goes for the `lastIndexOf...`